# Android notification isn't going off at specific time

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a notification go off at a 7:07 am every day. There isn't an error log to post since it's not actually throwing an error or crashing or anything like that, it's just... not going off when it should. Instead, the notification appears as soon as I open the app, and does not appear when it should.

Also, when I click on the notification, it doesn't go away (though it does bring me to the app, like it should). That's a secondary issue, though

```
        int mNotificationId = 001;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 07);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast
                (this, 1, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work if it is run after 7:07am. For example, in my time zone, right now, it is 9:40am. If I execute your code, the `Calendar` object points to *today* at 7:07am... which is in the past. You need to check to see if your `Calendar` is in the past, and if so, `add()` one day to it.

Also note that `setRepeating()` is inexact on API Level 19+.

Also note that you using `getBroadcast()` for your `PendingIntent`, but the `Intent` points to a component named `MainActivity`. If `MainActivity` is a `BroadcastReceiver`, you might want to consider changing the name. If, however, `MainActivity` is an `Activity`, your code will not work, because `getBroadcast()` creates a `PendingIntent` that sends a broadcast.

Comment: I chose 7:07 because it was a few minutes in the future. It does not work even if the first instance is in the future

Comment: @ThomasEliot: See updated answer. You might also want to look at LogCat to see what messages appear at the time your alarm event is supposed to occur.

Comment: `MainActivity` is an `Activity`. What should I have it send instead of a broadcast?

Comment: @ThomasEliot: Starting up an activity without warning is "not a good look". I strongly recommend that you stick with `getBroadcast()`, and create a `BroadcastReceiver` that raises a `Notification` at your desired time. If, OTOH, you insist on starting an activity, change `getBroadcast()` to `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Look for settings and search for something called "stamina mode" or similar thing which blocks waking up phone. This can be the problem and alarm fires up just when you wake up your phone.

Sec problem -> try this:

`mBuilder.setOngoing(false).build()` in `mNotifyMgr.notify` or something similar